# Razorpage in MVC will not call OnPost or without data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I Updated an MVC application from .net 3.1 to .net 6. (incl. startup to program.cs). Afterward added Razorpage in the program.cs by the * lines.

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
*builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    *endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Working good, except... The OnPost in the razorpage.

Default It won't fire when I post from the .cshtml page
If I decorate the class with

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
```

it fires, but without data, the model parameters are null.

Does anyone have experience with this and a solution?
Thank you

Comment: Can you share how you call the OnPost handler?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I had to fine its routing more.

I added

```
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "administration",
               pattern: "{controller=UserRolesViewModels}/{action=Administration}");
```

to my Programs folder then on my controller I defined the model route above each function with

```
[Route("manage")]
        [HttpPost]
```

Not sure I am doing it right as no one ever answers my questions here but it works for me.

Oh and dont forget the nav link. This is the most important.

```
     <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="UserRolesViewModels" asp-action="Administration">
                    <i class="ni ni-bullet-list-67 text-default"></i> User Management
                </a>
            </li>
```

Comment: Sorry TrixTahbit,
I was talking about the OnPost on Razor page.
Your solution looks like a MCV controller with views. Am I right?